# Matlab filtering records by date

Tags: matlab, select, filtering, contains

I'm a little rookie in Matlab and I met some trouble with my homework

I have Excel which looks like this :

```
Date          column A         column B
1/1/2015     (double)         (double)
5/1/2015     (double)         (double)
6/1/2015     (double)         (double)
12/2/2015     (double)         (double)
13/2/2015     (double)         (double)
15/3/2015     (double)         (double)
11/4/2015     (double)         (double)
12/4/2015     (double)         (double)
13/4/2015     (double)         (double)
11/5/2015     (double)         (double)
13/5/2015     (double)         (double)
11/6/2015     (double)         (double)
11/7/2015     (double)         (double)
11/8/2015     (double)         (double)
11/9/2015     (double)         (double)
11/10/2015     (double)         (double)
11/11/2015     (double)         (double)
11/12/2015     (double)         (double)
.
########(string?) ...          ...
########(string?) ...          ...
15/8/2018         ...          ...
.
.
.
```

I imported and converted it into a table, and now I need to filter it and leave only the first day of each quarter.

since Matlab is so different from things like MySQL, java, things I learned before and I got not much time, I'm panic in this desperate situation(it just a start of my homework!), so I really need some help.

I'm not familiar with the syntax and this the first time I asked a question, sorry if I ask something stupid.

Comment: I hope i could get some hints at least such as is there any syntax similar to str.contains("xxx"), or Select from where like '%xx%'

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add a few examples of what your data set looks like and what your expected result is like. This would help us help you :) Since Matlab isn't a database-type of programming language you'll need to read the data, and then program the logic you require. From the question, 'the logic you require' isn't very clear.

Comment: Since @CibinJoseph tell me that I'm not clear enough I've added few rows, the excel has  around  thousands of rows like this, a several years, I just, want to filter it by Date, keep only the first day of a season such as 1st of Jan Apr Jul sep, however not every seasons had 1st, it might start from 3rd or any date

Comment: no need to finish in one line, but better not too complicated since I'm not so familiar with Matlab and please don't loop every record, using filtering function

Comment: it can add new columns if necessary

Comment: Are your rows sorted by date? Also, do you only want to print column A and column B along with the corresponding extracted rows?

Comment: Yes the rows are sorted by date, just some dates are skipped

Answer (score 1):

```
table = readtable("a.csv");
table= table(month(table.Date)==4 | month(table.Date)==7 | month(table.Date)==10 | month(table.Date)==1, :);
```

just found a way that can filter specific month

now I just need to keep the first day of a month only and delete all other day

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [datetime](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/date-and-time-operations.html) class in Matlab to compare dates.

Assuming:
 1. Your dates are in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`
 2. Dates in column 1 are already sorted when printing out from Excel
 3. The delimiter for the csv file titled `data.csv` is a space,
the following snippet should print out the columns of the first occurring date of each quarter.

```matlab
clc; clear;

fid = fopen('data.csv');

% Retrieve data from file
data = textscan(fid, '%s %s %s', 'delimiter', ' ');

% Convert string to date objects 
% that enables date comparison
datesArray = datetime(data{1}, 'InputFormat', 'dd/MM/yyyy');

% Define start and end dates of each quarter
QstartDayMonth = ['01/01'; '01/04'; '01/07'; '01/10'];
QendDayMonth   = ['31/03'; '30/06'; '30/09'; '31/12'];

% Parse data to extract seasonal firsts
quart = 1;
for i = 1:length(datesArray)
  % Obtain year
  currentDate = datesArray(i);
  currentYear = num2str(currentDate.Year);

  % Define start date of current year's quarter
  quarterStart = strcat(QstartDayMonth(quart, :), '/', currentYear);
  quarterEnd   = strcat(QendDayMonth(quart, :)  , '/', currentYear);
  quarterStart = datetime(quarterStart, 'InputFormat', 'dd/MM/yyyy');
  quarterEnd   = datetime(quarterEnd, 'InputFormat', 'dd/MM/yyyy');

  % Check if current date lies in chosen quarter
  if (currentDate >= quarterStart)
    disp([data{1}{i}, '  ', data{2}{i}, '  ', data{3}{i}]);

    % If it does, advance the quarter to be checked
    quart = quart + 1;
    if (quart > 4)
      quart = 1;
    end
    continue;
  end
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: the date is dd/MM/yyyy in csv, but i found it will be yyyy-mm-dd while converted to table

Comment: Do i really need to use for loop or could it be finished by find(contains()), or table.value(continas())?, I tried by my self by I got error that I don't know how to handle

Comment: Unable to convert the text to datetime using the format 'yyyy-mm-dd'. error datesArray = datetime(data{1}, 'InputFormat', 'dd/MM/yyyy');

Comment: could this be done with a readtable() object? btw thx for help